# React onClick handler in map function . Cannot read property 'handleButton' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

I want to send table's row info to my handleButton function but I got this error:
Cannot read property 'handleButton' of undefined

Is it possible to send row info to a function other than the 'map' function?

I have one table. I fill this with map function and I need one button here.

```
 <Table data={this.state.data} striped bordered hover>
                            <thead>
                                <tr >
                                    <th>RowID</th>
                                    <th>Keyword</th>
                                    <th>Language</th>
                                    <th>Url</th>
                                    <th>Rank</th>
                                    <th>Like</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            {this.state.keywords.map(function(e){
                                return (
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{e.row_id}</td>
                                        <td>{e.target_language_keyword}</td>
                                        <td>{e.lang}</td>
                                        <td><a href={e.url} className="row-link">{e.url.toString().substring(0,40)}</a> </td>
                                        <td>{e.rank}</td>         
                                        <td><Button variant="success" onClick={() => {this.handleButton(this)}}  size="lg"> Like</Button></td>         
                                    </tr>
                                    
                            )})} 
                            
                            </tbody>
                        </Table>
```

I have also handleButton function like this

```
handleButton = event =>{
    
        alertify.success("Updated successfully")
              
    }
```

and in construnctur

```
 this.handleButton = this.handleButton.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Arrow function instead of binding method with this keyword

```js
 const handleButton =(event)=>{
    "Updated Successfully"
    }
```

and called it using onClick={this.handleButton}